# Interchanging limit and double series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I have a generating function
$$U(z,w)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_{j,n}z^jw^n$$
Where $0<z<1$, $0<w<1$, $0\leq u_{j,n}<1$.

Is is true for this series that
$$\lim_{z \to 1-}U(z,w)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_{j,n}w^n$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I did it correct yesterday; it does not logically sound correct. Here is another try.

If the following exists, then $U(1,\omega)$ exists and is equal to this.  $$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_{jn} \omega ^n$$

Let $$a_j=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_{jn} \omega ^n$$ then the following series convergence radius is greater than 1 for z, $$U(z,\omega) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_j z^j$$

The derivative to z is also convergent with the same convergence radius.
$$\frac {dU(z,\omega)}{dz} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} j a_j z^{j-1}$$ Particularly, when $z=1$
$$\frac {dU(1,\omega)}{dz} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} j a_j $$

Then we can apply $\epsilon - \delta$, for any $\epsilon$
$$|U(z, \omega) - U(1, \omega)|=|\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_j (z^j-1)|=|\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_j (z-1)(z^{j-1}+z^{j-2}+...+1)|$$

because $z \le 1$,
$$|U(z, \omega) - U(1, \omega)|\lt (1-z)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_j (z^{j-1}+z^{j-2}+...+1)\lt (1-z)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} j a_j = (1-z)\frac {dU(1,\omega)}{dz} $$

So I can find $$\delta =\frac {\epsilon} {\frac {dU(1,\omega)}{dz}}$$ such that for any z, $1-z \lt \delta$, $|U(z, \omega) - U(1, \omega)|\lt \epsilon $

Though completing this tedious work, I'm wondering if existence of derivative means it is continuous at 1 as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks. However i don't get how Abel's test and convergence imply this limit. Did you mean [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem)? Also i found that beacause of another Abel's theorem (for double power series) it converges absolutely and uniformly on |Z|<1, |w|<1. Is uniformity sufficient for this kind of limits interchange?